# All Commits From Every Branch Displayed During Pull Request on Github

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

Every time I push up code from my working branch that was either created by branching off another branch or branching off master, and I create a pull request and then all commits I have ever made show up on the pull request. These commits go 2 months back and are from multiple branches Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before pushing your branch from which you want to make a pull request, first:

- fetch from the original repo (the one with the master branch you want the maintainer to accept your pull request)
- rebase your branch on top of that fetched master branch
- then force push to your fork, and do your pull request: you will only see your commits

That is

```
cd /path/to/local/forked/repo
git remote add upstreamm https://url/original/repo
git fetch upstream
git checkout my-feature-branch
git rebase upstream/master
git push -u origin my-feature-branch # possibly add --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not precisely described, but in general Pull Request reflects the difference between the branch you want to merge into another branch and this another branch. Maybe you created your branch on which you were working out of the wrong or old branch that's why you're seeing too many commits during the Pull Request.

Comment: I make my branches off of master after I pull from master, and then when i pull from master it asks me for a commit message which i do not give. then on my current branch after i push it up and make a pull request there are hundreds of commit. my workflow does not change from project to project, and this is the only project it s happening on